# How to split Excel into several workbook with fixed number of rows count

Tags: vba, excel

I just started to learn VBA and I'm still not getting used with the codes yet.

Can anyone help me on how to split up Excel files into several workbooks based on number of rows? I have roughly 14k of Excel files that I need to consolidate into less than 10 workbooks.

During this consolidation, I want to set a condition where 1 workbook will only have maximum of 80k rows and the next data will be copied into a new workbook (Book2).

Following is the consolidation code that I have but where can I insert the row condition?

```
Sub MergeFiles()
Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

CurrFilename = ThisWorkbook.FullName

ary = Split(CurrFilename, "\")
bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), ".")
ary(UBound(ary)) = ""
CurrFilename2 = bry(0)

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
CurrTheLastRow = ActiveCell.Row
Range("A1:A" & CurrTheLastRow) = CurrFilename2

RowofCopySheet = 2

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

path = InputBox("Enter file path")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
    If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)

        ary = Split(Filename, "\")
        bry = Split(ary(UBound(ary)), ".")
        ary(UBound(ary)) = ""
        Filename2 = bry(0)


        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
        TheLastRow = ActiveCell.Row
        Range("A1:A" & TheLastRow) = Filename2

        Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
        CopyRng.Copy Dest
        Wkb.Close False
    End If

    Filename = Dir()
Loop

Range("A1").Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  copy/paste section with following

```
Dim WRCount  As Double
Dim WCCount  As Double
Dim MAXCount  As Double
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim LoopCount As Integer
Dim CellsToCopy As Double

LoopCount = 1
MAXCount = 80000
StartRow = 1
WRCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
WCCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Do While StartRow < WRCount

    CellsToCopy = StartRow + MAXCount

    If CellsToCopy > WRCount Then
        CellsToCopy = WRCount
    End If
    Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(CellsToCopy, WCCount))
    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(LoopCount)
    Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
    CopyRng.Copy Dest
    StartRow = StartRow + MAXCount
    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1
Loop
```

Comment: i tried the code but it turns out to be run time error 1004 occurred. any idea why this happened?

Comment: the debug pointed to  this line :
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(CellsToCopy, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))

Comment: I modified it . give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Since you are familiar with VBA, I will just give you some pseudo code.

Here's how I'd do it:

Loop through every workbook, in nested loop I would iterate until last row of a workbook, on every row copied I would increment some `Long` value, when it reaches 80k, then I would close current workbook, which we copy to, create another one and zero our counter:

```
If someLongValue = 80000 Then
    'close workbook
    'create another one
    someLongValue = 0
End If
```

Also, you can use file dialogs, instead of entering path in the `InputBox`, see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel